# D3.js: how to follow general update pattern to transition nested elements?

Tags: d3.js

I am working with D3.js, and learning the [general update pattern](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808234).

I understand it for simple data structures (I think!), but I would like to create a nested set of DOM elements: groups which contain paths and text elements. I'm not clear on how to access the update/enter/exit selection for the *nested* elements.

In summary, this is the SVG structure that I want to end up with:

```
<g class="team">
<path class="outer" d="..."></path>
<text class="legend" x="890" dy=".2em" y="23">Red Sox</text>   
</g>
<g class="team">
<path class="outer" d="..."></path>
<text class="legend" x="890" dy=".2em" y="23">Yankees</text>   
</g>
```

And I'd like to be able to access the update/enter/select selection explicitly on each element. My data looks like this:

```
[
{ "name": "Red Sox", "code": "RED", "results": [...] }, 
{ "name": "Yankees", "code": "YAN", "results": [...] }, 
]
```

And this is my code - see it in full at the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e2vdt/6/

```
function update(data) { 

  // Trying to follow the general update pattern:
  // http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808234

  // Join new data with old elements, if any.
  var g = vis.selectAll("g.team").data(data, function(d) { 
    return d.code;  
  });

  // Update old elements as needed. 
  // QUESTION: How to get the update selection for the text elements?
  // Currently the text element is not moving to the right position. 
  g.selectAll("text.legend").transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attr("y", function(d, i) { return i * 32 + 100; });

  // Create new elements as needed.
  var gEnter = g.enter()
      .append("g").attr("class","team");
  gEnter.append("text").attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("y", function(d, i) { return i * 32 + 100; })
      .attr("x", "20")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6)
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .transition()
      .duration(750)
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);
  // TBA: Add path element as well. 

  // Remove old elements as needed.
  g.exit()
    .transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attr("y", "0")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6)
    .remove();

}
```

The enter and exit selections are both working fine, but I don't know how to get the update selection so I can move the text labels to the correct position. The "Red Sox" entry should be moving down the page, but it isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's working fine, you just have to change how you position the g element.

```
  g.transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { 
      return "translate(0,"+(i * 32 + 100)+")"; 
    });
```

The `<g>` element has no `x` & `y` attributes, so you must position it using svg transforms.

Here's some more information about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG/Element/g

The adjusted example: http://jsfiddle.net/e2vdt/10/

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I'd explicitly like to position the `text` element rather than the `g` - that's because I want to position the `path` element too, once I've figured out how to do this. I've tried http://jsfiddle.net/e2vdt/11/ - I just don't know how to get the update selection for those text elements.

Comment: Ah, it's working as you expect - except you're updating it to.. exactly where it was. Look what happens if you adjust how the position is calculated for the update: http://jsfiddle.net/e2vdt/14/ (style also added for clarity)

Comment: Ah, that comment made my morning :) Thank you too!